# fsck results in a lost+found file that causes fsck to fail and cannot be removed

Tags: ext4, fsck, inode

I have an external drive with a single partition and ext4 filesystem with some corruption. A previous fsck was aborted by an unexpected power loss, and now I have a bad directory in lost+found that fsck now tries to repair each time it runs. When run, using fsck v1.43.3, `fsck -pv /dev/sda2`, shows: `hydra contains a file system with errors, check forced.` then a long check, then:
`hydra: Directory inode 18, block #0, offset 0: directory has no checksum.
FIXED.
Warning... fsck.ext4 for device /dev/sda2 exited with signal 9.`
When I mount the partition and look for that directory, it's within lost+found, but any attempts to access it fail. `ls: cannot access #18: Bad message`, `rm: cannot remove ‘#18’: Bad message`. Any ideas on how to remove it? It seems that this dirctory is causing fsck to abort prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

Signal 9 implies that you killed the process with kill -9.   Did you do that?

It would be useful for you to save a raw, compressed e2image (see the e2image man page) and also save a complete set of messages from running "e2fsck -fn /dev/sda2" so you can use it for sending a bug report to linux-ext4@vger.kernel.org.

If you want to clear inode #18, you can do this using the debugfs command:

```
# debugfs -w /dev/sda2
debugfs: clri <18>
debugfs: quit
```